# Port error on Ardour

Tags: audio, alsa, jack

I’m running Ubuntu Studio 18.10. In Ardour 5.12,.0-3. connecting to Jack, or ALSA, when I close a project then try to open another one, I get an error message that says “unable to create port: failed constructor. Click the Close button and try again”. The only way for me to open another project is to close then reopen Ardour. I tried deleting the instant.xml files, but that did not seem to help. No control surfaces are checked. I think that Ardour is set to handle many more tracks than I have. I have also exported the projects as archives, and imported them into Ubuntu Studio 18.10 on VirtualBox, and I don’t seem to have the same problem. Would completely uninstalling Ardour, then reinstalling help? I wonder if I installed an app that is interfering somehow with Ardour. Any suggestions as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. 
In my case I start a project with 44.1kHz and after I reopen Ardour it want to work with 48kHz.

I've got the work around to use "QjackCtl". There are two ways I found out.

1. Create a config (propably use debugging). Important is to setup the correct input and output device. 
   Now you have to start the jack session in qjackctl and hook up with Ardour.
2. (gladish will also work for this way) After you quit Ardour check the state of the Jack session with qjackctl. If the stop button is red and not greyed out, then you have to stop the session. 
   If you will start Ardour, it will handle the start of the Jack session.